# Create vscode keybinding for bold and italic text

Tags: shortcut

I would like to create a keyboard binding (for Visual Studio Code) where when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, it writes `\textbf{...}` and put me into insert mode with the cursor inside the braces.

Right now I have solution from here

https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/434

but it doesn't put my cursor inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the link you provided, you can use Visual Studio Codes internal `keybindings.json` ([documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)) file to do this.

This works for me on macOS:

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+B",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorLangId == latex && editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "\\textbf{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$0}"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+I",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorLangId == latex && editorTextFocus",  // chained clause
        "args": {
            "snippet": "\\textit{${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$0}"
        }
    }
```

For non-macOS users, replace `cmd` with `ctrl`.

This is different from the solution on the github issue in that: under the snippet key, the cursor focus `$0` of the first parameter is moved from outside the parenthesis to within.

Comment: You might need to use `ctrl` instead of `cmd` in the definition of key if you don't use mac.

Comment: Thanks @PetrR. I edited my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good extension which can help you with this. It is called [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop).
To make bold the shortcut is **Ctrl+L** **Ctrl+B**. This extension has many other features that can be helpful.

Comment: The LaTeX Workshop keybinding is actually **Ctrl+L Ctrl+B** to bold and **Ctrl+L Ctrl+I** to italicize.